# Multiple platform condition in XAML view - Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to use platform condition in Xaml like if we want to use one control for IOS and another for Android so how can we put any condition to achieve this. 
I don't just need to set any properties to existing control I've to add more control in a view

Comment: Check out [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/160773/#Comment_160773) link for an example of using `OnPlatform` with a control in XAML.

Comment: @Jason The link provided as answer/duplicate is using old OnPlatform syntax.

Comment: I added an answer there using newer syntax

Comment: My question is different OnPlatform only support properties I have to define different components under onplatform but Onplatform doesn't support nested tags

Comment: This is falsely flagged as duplicate. Hasan is asking about nesting different xaml according to platform. Here's how: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/160773/#Comment_160773